# Perl Regex Capture

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following text:

```
GET /mac/_base_v1/images/chrome/background_repeat.jpg HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.microsoft.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0  
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/base-css  
DNT: 1  
Connection: keep-alive  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Cache-Control: max-age=900  
Content-Type: image/jpegGET /mac/_base_v1/modules/button/images  /buttonlarge_yellownormal.png HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.microsoft.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0   
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/css  
DNT: 1
```

and the following Perl regex

```
while ($1 =~m/((GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT)\s+\S+)(?:(?!GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT\s+\S+).)*?Host:\s([^\n]+).*?User-Agent:\s([^\n]+).*?Referer:\s([^\n]+).*?Connection:/msg) {
    # do something
}
```

and it matches this fine

```
GET /mac/_base_v1/modules/button/images/buttonlarge_yellownormal.png  
www.microsoft.com  
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0  
http://www.microsoft.com/mac/css
```

However, I also need it to examine the following text:

```
GET /vi/k_dbVP4r4V4/hqdefault.jpg HTTP/1.1  
Host: i.ytimg.com  
User-Agent: Apple iPad v4.3.5 YouTube v1.0.0.8L1  
Accept-Language: en-us, *;q=0.5  
Gdata-Version: 2  
X-Gdata-Client: ytapi-apple-ipad  
Accept: */*  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Connection: keep-alive  
Q2J}
```

and match the following:

```
GET /vi/k_dbVP4r4V4/hqdefault.jpg HTTP/1.1  
i.ytimg.com  
Apple iPad v4.3.5 YouTube v1.0.0.8L1
```

while still being able to match the previous text presented successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP requests and responses headers are not as trivial to parse as expected. For example, the following are all equivalent:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Encoding: gzip,
    deflate

Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Encoding: deflate
```

As such, I recommend you use an existing parser

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use HTTP::Request qw( );

my $s = <<'__EOI__';
GET /mac/_base_v1/images/chrome/background_repeat.jpg HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.microsoft.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0  
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/base-css  
DNT: 1  
Connection: keep-alive  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Cache-Control: max-age=900  
Content-Type: image/jpegGET /mac/_base_v1/modules/button/images  /buttonlarge_yellownormal.png HTTP/1.1  
Host: www.microsoft.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0   
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Referer: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/css  
DNT: 1  
__EOI__

my ($raw_req, $raw_resp) = split qr{(?=^HTTP/)}m, $s;
my $req = HTTP::Request->parse($raw_req);
say $req->method;
say $req->url;
say $req->user_agent;
say $req->header('User-Agent');  # Same as previous
```

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand your question correctly, you need the Referrer header to be optional.  You can do that by adding non-capturing parentheses around the portion of your regex that matches that header and placing a question mark after your closing parenthesis:

```
(?:Referer:\s([^\n]+))?
```

If any other headers are optional, you can do the same thing with them.

EDIT: The data stops being captured after the first missing header.

This isn't perfect yet, because it doesn't work if there are multiple HTTP requests in a single data file, but it should get you going in the right direction:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = <<'END_OF_STR';
GET /vi/k_dbVP4r4V4/hqdefault.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: i.ytimg.com
User-Agent: Apple iPad v4.3.5 YouTube v1.0.0.8L1
Accept-Language: en-us, *;q=0.5
Gdata-Version: 2
X-Gdata-Client: ytapi-apple-ipad
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
END_OF_STR

my @lines = split m/[\n]/xms, $str;

# Build the regex to match the HTTP methods we care about.
my @methods = qw(GET PUT POST CONNECT);
my $methods_re = join '|', map { quotemeta $_ } @methods;

# Skip to the first request line and print it.
while ( $lines[0] !~ m/ \A $methods_re /xms ) {
    shift @lines;
}
print "$lines[0]\n";
shift @lines;

# Build the regex to match the headers we care about.
my @headers = qw(Host User-Agent Referer Connection);
my $headers_re = join '|', map { quotemeta $_ } @headers;

# Find the headers that we matched.
for my $line (@lines) {
    if ( $line =~ m/ \A (?:$headers_re):\s*(.*) /xms ) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

exit;
```

I'll add another update shortly that will account for multiple HTTP requests in a single file.

EDIT: This solution correctly prints the values you're looking for, but it only prints them.  If you want to get the values for each specific request then something more complex will be required.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = <<'END_OF_STR';
GET /vi/k_dbVP4r4V4/hqdefault.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: i.ytimg.com
User-Agent: Apple iPad v4.3.5 YouTube v1.0.0.8L1
Accept-Language: en-us, *;q=0.5
Gdata-Version: 2
X-Gdata-Client: ytapi-apple-ipad
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
END_OF_STR

my @lines = split m/[\n]/xms, $str;

# Build the regexes to match the HTTP methods and headers we care about.
my @methods = qw(GET PUT POST CONNECT);
my $methods_re = join '|', map { quotemeta $_ } @methods;
my @headers = qw(Host User-Agent Referer Connection);
my $headers_re = join '|', map { quotemeta $_ } @headers;

for my $line (@lines) {
    if ( $line =~ m/ \A $methods_re /xms ) {
        print "$line\n";
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/ \A (?:$headers_re):\s*(.*) /xms ) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

exit;
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for the reply.  I always need to capture the Referer if it exists along with the other captures and be able to capture the other captures if the Referer does not exist.  Will appedning your solution to my regex work?  Thx

Comment: Hi Dennis I tried the following and unfortunately it didn't match what I wanted ((GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT)\s+\S+)(?:(?!GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT\s+\S+).)*?Host:\s([^\n]+).*?User-Agent:\s([^\n]+).*?(?:Referer:\s([^\n]+))?    any other suggestions appreciated

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean; the regex matches, but the captures stop after the first non-matching regex.  The easiest solution is probably to handle each line separately.  I'll update the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thx. I should also mention for what it is worth that this data is part of a large slurped file into memory I am doing the regex match against.  Thx again

Comment: Does the data contain more than one HTTP request?

Comment: It can contain 1 or many.  So my original regex will match all data flow of interest except for when it incounters a flow of interest that doesn't contain a Referer.

Comment: By the way, you may want to read the file a line at a time if you can.  Slurping then doing the split is likely to consume a lot of memory and will take longer than just reading the file a line at a time.

Comment: Reply thank you Dennis I will test this solution out and work to break my existing solution up into multiple lines per your suggestion.  Thank you again!